# I want to preserve line breaks in CharField in Django REST framework

Tags: django

I'm using a CharField in the Django REST framework to store text, but how can I preserve line breaks in the API?

In the case of Django templates, I think line breaks are possible with `{{ value|linebreaksbr }}`, but what about the Django REST framework?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CharField` in mainly for storing string if you want to store long text along with line break use `TextField`.

```py
class TestModel(models.Model):
    string = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=50)
```

[image]

Now try to get the data in django shell and observer.

```py
>>> from apps.users.models import TestModel
>>> x = TestModel.objects.first()
>>> x.string
'Here is /n new line'
>>> x.text
'Here is\r\nnew\r\nline'
>>> print(x.text)
Here is
new
line
>>> print(x.string)
Here is /n new line
```

Hope it helps. and that's the standard way to store text with linebreak as far I have seen.